# How to make UI binding more efficient in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

This is an example I found but not sure if this is the most efficient way of setting up a UI. If you could explain any way of making this more efficient or is there another, more efficient, way of setting this out.

I have left out a class called module as it is not needed to see if the controller is efficient or not.

```
package WRAV;

import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Controller {

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // list of Students
    private ArrayList<StudentModel> students;

    public ArrayList<StudentModel> getStuds(){ return students;}
    // the index of the current student
    private IntegerProperty currentIndex = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);

    // the number of student
    private IntegerProperty currentSize = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

    // the current student being viewed and edited
    private Property<StudentModel> currentStudent = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    // some getter methods for the properties
    public int getCurrentIndex() {
        return currentIndex.get();
    }

    public StudentModel getCurrentStudent() {
        return currentStudent.getValue();
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //List of all current students modules
    private ArrayList<Module> studentModules = new ArrayList<Module>();

    // the current module
    private Property<Module> currentModule = new SimpleObjectProperty<Module>();

    //the index of the current module
    private IntegerProperty currentModIndex = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);

    //the number of modules
    private IntegerProperty currentModSize = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

    // some getter methods for the properties
    public int getCurrentModIndex() {return  currentModIndex.get();}

    public Module getCurrentModule() { return  currentModule.getValue() ;}

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // navigation methods

    public void first() {
        System.out.println("|<\tFirst.");

        if (students.size() > 0)
            currentIndex.set(0);
    }

    public void last() {
        System.out.println(">|\tLast.");

        if (students.size() > 0)
            currentIndex.set(students.size() - 1);
    }

    public void next() {
        System.out.println(">>\tNext.");

        if (currentIndex.get() < (students.size() - 1))
            currentIndex.set(currentIndex.get() + 1);

        currentModIndex.setValue(1);
        setUpMod();
    }

    public void previous() {
        System.out.println("<<\tPrev.");

        if (currentIndex.get() > 0)
            currentIndex.set(currentIndex.get() - 1);

        currentModIndex.setValue(1);
        setUpMod();
    }

    public void newStudent() {
        System.out.println("[]\tNew.");

        // create new student
        StudentModel student = new StudentModel("?", "?", "?");

        studentModules.clear();
        newMod();

        // add to student
        students.add(student);

        // update size property
        currentSize.set(students.size());

        // set current to last
        last();

        currentModIndex.setValue(1);
        setUpMod();
    }

    public void removeStudent(){
        if (students.size() != 0) {
            System.out.println("[]\tRemove.");

            // remove current student
            students.remove(getCurrentIndex());

            System.out.println(students.size());

            // update size property
            currentSize.set(students.size());

            // set current to last

            last();

            if (students.size() == 0){
                newStudent();
            }

            currentModIndex.setValue(1);
            setUpMod();
        }



    }

    private void setupProperties() {
        System.out.println("Setting up properties.");

        // change the current student if the current index changes
        currentIndex.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            // if new index value within the allowed range, get the student
            if ((newValue.intValue() >= 0) && (newValue.intValue() < students.size())) {
                System.out.printf("Current index changed, old = %s, new = %s\n", oldValue.intValue(), newValue.intValue());
                currentStudent.setValue(students.get(newValue.intValue()));
            }
        });

        // update bindings to the current student if it changed
        currentStudent.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.printf("Student changed, old = %s, new = %s\n", oldValue, newValue);
            rebindFields(oldValue, newValue);
        });
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public void firstMod() {
        System.out.println("|<\tFirst Module");

        if (studentModules.size() > 0)
            currentModIndex.set(0);
    }

    public void lastMod() {
        System.out.println(">|\tLast Module");

        if (getCurrentStudent().modules.size() > 0)
            currentModIndex.set(getCurrentStudent().modules.size() - 1);
    }

    public void nextMod() {
        System.out.println(">>\tNext Module");

        if (currentModIndex.get() < (getCurrentStudent().modules.size() - 1))
            currentModIndex.set(currentModIndex.get() + 1);
    }

    public void previousMod() {
        System.out.println("<<\tPrev Module");

        if (currentModIndex.get() > 0)
            currentModIndex.set(currentModIndex.get() - 1);
    }

    public void newMod() {
        System.out.println("[]\tNew Module");

        // create new module
        StudentModel cur = getCurrentStudent();
        Module add = new Module("?", "?", 0, 0);
        // add to contacts
        cur.addModule(add);

        // update size property
        currentModSize.set(studentModules.size());

        // set current to last
        lastMod();
    }

    public void removeMod(){
        if (studentModules.size() != 0) {
            System.out.println("[]\tRemove Module");

            // remove current module
            studentModules.remove(getCurrentModIndex());

            System.out.println(studentModules.size());

            // update size property
            currentModSize.set(studentModules.size());

            // set current to last

            last();

            if (studentModules.size() == 0){
                newMod();
            }
        }

    }

    private void setupModProperties() {
        System.out.println("Setting up module properties.");

        // change the current module if the current index changes
        currentModIndex.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            // if new index value within the allowed range, get the module
            if ((newValue.intValue() >= 0) && (newValue.intValue() < studentModules.size())) {
                System.out.printf("Current module index changed, old = %s, new = %s\n", oldValue.intValue(), newValue.intValue());
                currentModule.setValue(studentModules.get(newValue.intValue()));
            }
        });

        // update bindings to the current module if it changed
        currentModule.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.printf("Module changed, old = %s, new = %s\n", oldValue, newValue);
            rebindModFields(oldValue, newValue);
        });

    }

    public void setUp(){
        System.out.println("|<\tSetup.");

        if (students.size() > 0)
            currentIndex.set(0);

        currentSize.set(students.size());

        setUpMod();
    }

    public void setUpMod(){

        studentModules = getCurrentStudent().modules;

        if (studentModules.size() > 0)
            currentModIndex.set(0);
        else {
            newMod();
        }

        currentModSize.set(studentModules.size());

    }

    public Controller(ArrayList<StudentModel> arrayList) {
        students = arrayList;
        setupProperties();
        setupModProperties();
    }


    // references to scene's controls///////////////////////////////////////////
    private Button btnAddStud;
    private Button btnDelStud;
    private TextField txtSNum;
    private TextField txtSName;
    private TextField txtName;
    private Label lblSetAVG;
    private Button btnStudLeft;
    private Button btnStudRight;
    private Label lblStudOf;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private Button btnAddMod;
    private Button btnDelMod;
    private TextField txtCode;
    private TextField txtDiscrip;
    private TextField txtGrade;
    private TextField txtYear;
    private Label lblSetResult;
    private Button btnModLeft;
    private Button btnModRight;
    private Label lblModOf;

    /**
     * Unbinds any bindings to the text fields, then rebinds to the current
     * properties.
     */
    private void rebindFields(StudentModel oldStudent, StudentModel newStudent) {
        // remove old bindings to the old student
        if (oldStudent != null) {
            System.out.println("Removing text field bi-directional bindings from " + oldStudent);
            txtName.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldStudent.name);
            txtSName.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldStudent.sname);
            txtSNum.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldStudent.studentNumber);
            lblSetAVG.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldStudent.average);
        }

        // add bindings to new student
        if (newStudent != null) {
            System.out.println("Adding text field bi-directional bindings to " + newStudent);
            txtName.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newStudent.name);
            txtSName.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newStudent.sname);
            txtSNum.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newStudent.studentNumber);
            lblSetAVG.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newStudent.average);
        }
    }

    private void rebindModFields(Module oldModule, Module newModule) {
        // remove old bindings to the old module
        if (oldModule != null) {
            System.out.println("Removing text field bi-directional bindings from " + oldModule);
            txtCode.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldModule.modCode);
            txtDiscrip.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldModule.modDiscrip);
            txtGrade.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldModule.modGrade);
            txtYear.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldModule.modYear);
            lblSetResult.textProperty().unbindBidirectional(oldModule.passed);
        }

        // add bindings to new module
        if (newModule != null) {
            System.out.println("Adding text field bi-directional bindings to " + newModule);
            txtCode.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newModule.modCode);
            txtDiscrip.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newModule.modDiscrip);
            txtGrade.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newModule.modGrade);
            txtYear.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newModule.modYear);
            lblSetResult.textProperty().bindBidirectional(newModule.passed);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Bind the UI controls and the controller properties together.
     * @param scene
     */
    public void connectToUI(Scene scene) {
        // obtain references to controls
        System.out.println("Obtaining references to scene controls by id.");

        txtName = (TextField) scene.lookup("#Name");
        txtSNum = (TextField) scene.lookup("#sNum");
        txtSName = (TextField) scene.lookup("#SName");
        btnStudLeft = (Button) scene.lookup("#StudLeft");
        btnStudRight = (Button) scene.lookup("#StudRight");
        btnAddStud = (Button) scene.lookup("#AddStud");
        btnDelStud = (Button) scene.lookup("#DelStud");
        lblSetAVG = (Label) scene.lookup("#SetAVG");
        lblStudOf = (Label) scene.lookup("#StudOf");
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        txtCode = (TextField) scene.lookup("#ModCode");
        txtDiscrip = (TextField) scene.lookup("#ModDiscrip");
        txtGrade = (TextField) scene.lookup("#ModGrade");
        txtYear = (TextField) scene.lookup("#ModYear");
        btnModLeft = (Button) scene.lookup("#ModLeft");
        btnModRight = (Button) scene.lookup("#ModRight");
        btnAddMod = (Button) scene.lookup("#AddMod");
        btnDelMod = (Button) scene.lookup("#DelMod");
        lblSetResult = (Label) scene.lookup("#SetResult");
        lblModOf = (Label) scene.lookup("#ModOf");



        System.out.println("Attaching listeners to controls and properties.");

        // modify label using a Fluent binding
        lblStudOf.textProperty().bind( currentIndex.add(1).asString().concat(" of ").concat(currentSize));

        // initialise size - which will initialise the binding
        currentSize.set(students.size());

        // attach event handlers to the buttons
        btnStudLeft.setOnAction(event -> previous());
        btnAddStud.setOnAction(event -> newStudent());
        btnDelStud.setOnAction(event -> removeStudent());
        btnStudRight.setOnAction(event -> next());

        // modify label using a binding
        lblModOf.textProperty().bind( currentModIndex.add(1).asString().concat(" of ").concat(currentModSize));

        // initialise size
        currentModSize.set(studentModules.size());

        // attach event handlers to the buttons
        btnModLeft.setOnAction(event -> previousMod());
        btnAddMod.setOnAction(event -> newMod());
        btnDelMod.setOnAction(event -> removeMod());
        btnModRight.setOnAction(event -> nextMod());

        txtGrade.focusedProperty().addListener((arg0, oldPropertyValue, newPropertyValue) -> {
            if ( Integer.parseInt(txtGrade.getText()) > 50) {
                    getCurrentModule().didPass();
                    lblSetResult.setText("Pass");
                }
             else {
                lblSetResult.setText("Fail");
            }

            lblSetAVG.setText(getCurrentStudent().calcAverage());


        });

    }

    public void clear(){
        students.clear();
    }
}







public class StudentModel {
    public StringProperty studentNumber = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    public StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    public StringProperty sname = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    public StringProperty average = new SimpleStringProperty("0");
    public ArrayList<Module> modules = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String sLine = studentNumber.get() + ", " +  name.get() + ", " +  sname.get() + ", " + average.get();

        for (int i = 0; i < modules.size(); i++) {
            sLine += "\n " + modules.get(i).toString() + ", ";
        }

        return sLine;

    }

    public StudentModel(String studentNumber, String sname, String name) {
        this.studentNumber.set(studentNumber);
        this.name.set(name);
        this.sname.set(sname);

    }

    public void addModules(NodeList m){
        for (int i = 0; i < m.getLength(); i++) {
            NodeList children = m.item(i).getChildNodes();
            Module add = (new Module(children.item(1).getTextContent(), children.item(3).getTextContent(), Integer.parseInt(children.item(5).getTextContent()), Integer.parseInt(children.item(7).getTextContent())));
            modules.add(add);
        }

        this.average.set(String.valueOf(calcAverage()));
    }

    public void addModule(Module m){
        modules.add(m);
    }

    public String calcAverage(){
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < modules.size(); i++) {
            sum +=  Integer.parseInt(modules.get(i).modGrade.getValue());
        }

        if (modules.size() != 0) {
            average.setValue(String.valueOf(1.00 * (sum / modules.size())));
        }

        return average.getValue();
    }

    public Element toNode(Document doc){

        Element stud = doc.createElement("student");
        stud.appendChild(getCompanyElements(doc, stud, "snum", studentNumber.getValue()));
        stud.appendChild(getCompanyElements(doc, stud, "surname", sname.getValue()));
        stud.appendChild(getCompanyElements(doc, stud, "name", name.getValue()));

        Element mods = doc.createElement(("modules"));

        for (int i = 0; i < modules.size(); i++) {
            mods.appendChild(modules.get(i).toNode(doc));
        }

        stud.appendChild(mods);

        return stud;


    }

    private static Node getCompanyElements(Document doc, Element element, String name, String value) {
        Element node = doc.createElement(name);
        node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value));
        return node;
    }
}'
```

I would appreciate this thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Jeff! Are there specific lines in this example code that you are asking about? As it is now, your question is a little too broad and open ended. See if you can narrow it down a bit, point out which bits you think are inefficient.

Comment: You can also consider asking this type of question on codereview.stackexchange.com where you might get more detailed answers.